# How do I use Racket's rectangle function to draw a checkerboard-like square of variable sizes?

Tags: graphics, scheme, racket

I have a 2D array of numbers that I would like to use to generate a checkerboard-like image [like the one here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0FiO.png) with the rectangle function in Racket. Each number in the array should correspond to a colored square (the number will determine the color of the square).

I tried

```
    (beside
     (for ([i (in-range 3)])
       (rectangle 20 40 "solid" "blue")
       )
     )
```

in an attempt to draw 3 blue rectangles side by side before attempting to create the full "checkerboard", but I received an arity mismatch error.

Any tips on how to get my desired end result?

Comment: `beside` doesn't consume one list of images, but it consumes many arguments where each argument is an image. 

Use `apply` to turn a list of values into multiple arguments. Use `for/list` so that the for-expression generates a list instead of `(void)`.

E.g., `(apply beside (for/list ([i (in-range 3)]) (rectangle 20 40 "solid" "blue")))`

Comment: @SoraweePorncharoenwase That looks more like an answer than a comment.